# How to sort sphinx result by document id

Tags: php, mysql, search, sorting, sphinx

I want to sort my sphinx result with document id. By any change can I set any default sorting mode in a particular sphinx index result. If possible how can I given that. Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what have tried till now.

But i think below snippet will get you the desired result:

```
$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@id asc');
```

Hope this help.